# Semantic UI Modal fixed position

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI 2.1. I have a modal which displays pictures. The pictures are varying sizes. I then have nav buttons to move back and forth between the pictures. The modal wants to keep resizing/recentering itself as I move through the photos. What that means is the navigation buttons keep moving up and down  so a user can't just click, click, click to move through the photos. They have to click, move mouse, click, move mouse, etc.

Is it possible to have the modal fixed to the top? I am happy for it to resize but at a fixed top position. That way the nav buttons will stay under the user's mouse cursor.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out??

Comment: @NickYoung I had to add my own modal and not use the semantic one.